# FFT Plot of an Audio Signal - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing, fft, audio-processing

I'm using MATLAB to plot a recorded sound using the FFT. I want to take the `log` of the y-axis but I don't know what I did if correct.

Currently, my FFT plotting code looks like this:

```
nf=1024; %number of point in DTFT   
Y = fft(y,nf);    
f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,nf/2+1);    
plot(f,abs(Y(1:nf/2+1)));    
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)')   
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')   
ylabel('|Y(f)|')
```

What I did is: `plot(f,log(Y(1:nf/2+1)));`.  I replaced `abs` with `log`. Is this correct?

Comment: So did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Applying `log` on the coefficients itself doesn't make any sense... especially since the spectra will be complex-valued in nature.  However, some people usually apply the `log` on the **magnitude** of the spectra (hence the `abs` call) mostly for visualization purposes so that large values of the magnitude don't overwhelm the smaller values.  Applying `log` in this case will allow the larger values to taper off and the spectrum can be visualized easier. but applying the straight `log` in my opinion isn't correct.  The code you have provided plots the magnitude of the single-sided spectrum and so there's no need to change anything.

If you provided more insight as to **why** you want to use the `log`, that would be helpful but right now, I would say that the straight `log` is incorrect.  However, if you really must use the `log`, apply it on the **magnitude** instead.  Also, to prevent undefined behaviour, make sure you add 1 to the magnitude before applying the `log` so that zero values of your magnitude get mapped to zero, rather than undefined.

As such, do this instead:

```
nf=1024; %number of point in DTFT   
Y = fft(y,nf);    
f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,nf/2+1);    
plot(f,log(1 + abs(Y(1:nf/2+1)))); %// Change    
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)')   
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')   
ylabel('|Y(f)|')
```